# React Inline styles clashes with the Client CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

We need to load our application in the clients page. We are building them using React. So, We are using React Inline Styles by defining the style as Objects. But we encountered an issue. When the client specified any css by using tag attributes. The property which we never defined in inline get the property used in the tag attribute of the client css.

This below code is the react inline style we used for the navbar.

```
var style = {
navigation: {
    minWidth: '50px ',
    position: 'relative ',
    marginBottom: '20px ',
    border: '1px solid transparent '
},
};
render function() {
 return(<nav style={style.navigation}> ...... </nav>);
}
```

In the client side he is using the style tag attribute for defining the navbar.

```
nav{height:40px;}
```

In this above case, the nav attribute defined by the client is also added to our inline styling and causing much trouble.

Suggest some better solutions. Using Reset class is the only solution in this case
??

Comment: it will take up those css obviously. what you can do is to override them or remove those unwanted styles

Comment: Hey piyush. Thanks for the reply. But it is from the client css page. So is reset is the only way to do that. ?

Comment: not reset actually just  override them. that's the way and also you can provide classNames as well for different tags

Comment: I understand, But the fact is, There are many clients using our product so it is impossible to override every style properties in our style object for every client. So, is there is any way to stop the client css to be applied in our component.

Comment: if that's the scenario then only override is the option. For overriding you have to mention every style you want. just pass those as inline as "null"

Comment: Okay. Will check about that.

Comment: glad if it could have helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset any CSS styles in your component that are affected by the client's CSS. One method to do this would be to use the [CSS `all` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all).

> The CSS all shorthand property resets all properties, apart from unicode-bidi and direction, to their initial or inherited value.

The problem with this solution is `all` is not supported in IE or Edge.

```
var style = {
  navigation: {
    all: 'initial',
    minWidth: '50px ',
    position: 'relative ',
    marginBottom: '20px ',
    border: '1px solid transparent '
  },
};

render function() {
  return(<nav style={style.navigation}> ...... </nav>);
}
```

Here's an example of this in action - showing the same `<Nav />` component, one using the CSS `all: initial` property, the other without. As said before, this will not work on Internet Explorer or Edge.

```js
class Nav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var style = {
      navigationWithAll: {
        all: 'initial',
        border: '1px solid red'
      },
      navigation: {
        minWidth: '50px ',
        position: 'relative ',
        marginBottom: '20px ',
        border: '1px solid red'
      }
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <nav style={style.navigation}>Navigation</nav>
        <nav style={style.navigationWithAll}>Navigation</nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Nav />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
nav {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

If you need to support IE or Edge, which is probably the case, you will need to reset the specific CSS properties which are being inherited. This could be done with something as simple as the following:

```
styles = {
  navigation: {
    height: 'initial'
  }
}
```

but a more robust solution, which would work across all client sites would be to import a CSS component reset.

```
reset = {
    margin: 'initial',
    padding: 'initial',
    height : 'auto',
    height: 'initial',
    width: 'auto',
    // any other properties you want to reset, or a full list of CSS properties to reset to initial/auto
  }
}
```

Then import this reset into your component styles

```
import reset from 'reset'  

styles = {
  navigation: {
    ...reset,
    border: 1px solid red,
    // your custom styles
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brett for your time and help. Will test this solution.